# autocompletion without dialog

Tags: python, prompt-toolkit

Does the prompt-toolkit module supports autocompletion without displaying a dialog box (using tab to autocomplete)? I find the dialog box a bit bulky and overkill when there are a fairly large number of options to autocomplete with.

A-la bash-shell or comparable, using either prompt() or session.prompt()?

[image]

Thank you for looking.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from prompt_toolkit.shortcuts import CompleteStyle
[...]
session = PromptSession(lexer=PygmentsLexer(...), completer=commands, complete_while_typing=True, complete_style=CompleteStyle.READLINE_LIKE)
```

Comment: Would clearly state the question you want answered?